# Firefox on Lubuntu opens half of its height on startup and then maximizes

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, lxde

Couldn't come up with something better for the title.

But I'm trying to explain it better (and the GIF below explains it even better graphically). So, when I open Firefox on Lubuntu, no matter if it's from the Desktop shortcut (.desktop) or from the Terminal, instead of opening the Firefox right away in maximized it first goes half the screen height and THEN maximizes. So there's some sort of a lag.
Of course I've tried setting the width and height parameters, e.g. `firefox -width 1280 -height 1024` and the "maximize" parameter `firefox --window --maximize`. None of those worked.

Since Lubuntu is meant for low performance hardware, I think hardware isn't an issue. I haven't seen this problem on Ubuntu and Linux Mint (yea, I know that these are a with bit different architecture than Lubuntu), which I've both used on this computer. I switched to Lubuntu, because it's more leightweight.

Here's a GIF to illustrate what behaviour is bugging me:
[image: illustration]

Comment: The gif isn't working.

Comment: It is. OP's point is valid!

Comment: OP, if you can, please snap your Firefox window to left half or right of your screen and then exit Firefox. When you restart Firefox, you should see Firefox open in the left half or right half of your screen instead of what it's doing now (upper half). Please edit your question to provide the additional info.

Comment: "you should see Firefox open in the left half or right half of your screen" >>> "you should see Firefox open ***transiently*** in the left half or right half of your screen inste"

Comment: This happens on my system too --> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @SeverusTux, I'm on Lubuntu 16.04 as well. I posted what works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me is to go into about:config and turn the following to `false` from `true`:

`layers.offmainthreadcomposition.async-animations`

and

`layers.offmainthreadcomposition.enabled`

[image: about:config]

A couple of related links:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/40.0beta/releasenotes/ mentions "Improved scrolling, graphics, and video playback performance with off main thread compositing (GNU/Linux only)".

And the Arch wiki has more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firefox_tweaks#Enable_OpenGL_Off-Main-Thread_Compositing_.28OMTC.29

Comment: wow! this works perfectly :-) . Thanks @DKBose